# How to use glDrawVertex() function in ANSI C

Tags: c, linux, opengl, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to use `glDrawArrays()` but I always get segmentation fault on `glDrawArrays` call. Am I doing something wrong?

```
/*MESH*/
struct Mesh
{
 GLsizei numVertices;
 GLfloat vertices[48];
} m;

static void meshCreate(struct Mesh *mesh)
{
 mesh->vertices[0] = 0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[1] = -0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[2] = -0.800000f;
 mesh->vertices[3] = 0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[4] = 0.158333f;
 mesh->vertices[5] = -0.177084f;
 mesh->vertices[6] = 0.300000f;
 mesh->vertices[7] = -0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[8] = -0.300000f;
 mesh->vertices[9] = -0.300000f;
 mesh->vertices[10] = -0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[11] = -0.300000f;
 mesh->vertices[12] = 0.300000f;
 mesh->vertices[13] = 0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[14] = 0.300000f;
 mesh->vertices[15] = -0.300000f;
 mesh->vertices[16] = 0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[17] = 0.300000f;
 mesh->vertices[18] = 0.177084f;
 mesh->vertices[19] = 0.158333f;
 mesh->vertices[20] = -0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[21] = 0.800000f;
 mesh->vertices[22] = -0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[23] = -0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[24] = -0.177083f;
 mesh->vertices[25] = 0.158333f;
 mesh->vertices[26] = -0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[27] = -0.800000f;
 mesh->vertices[28] = -0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[29] = -0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[30] = 0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[31] = 0.158333f;
 mesh->vertices[32] = 0.177083f;
 mesh->vertices[33] = 0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[34] = 0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[35] = 0.800000f;
 mesh->vertices[36] = 0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[37] = -0.158333f;
 mesh->vertices[38] = -0.177084f;
 mesh->vertices[39] = 0.177084f;
 mesh->vertices[40] = -0.158333f;
 mesh->vertices[41] = -0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[42] = -0.177083f;
 mesh->vertices[43] = -0.158333f;
 mesh->vertices[44] = -0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[45] = 0.000000f;
 mesh->vertices[46] = -0.158333f;
 mesh->vertices[47] = 0.177083f;

 mesh->numVertices = 48;

 logAdd(&gameLog, "Info: Mesh loaded.");
}

static void meshRender(struct Mesh *mesh)
{
 glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, mesh->vertices);
 glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, mesh->numVertices); //<- here segmentation fault
}

//edit

meshCreate(&m); //OK
printf("%f", m.vertices[47]);//OK - variable m exists and has good values

//begin of loop
glClear();
meshRender(&m); //<-segfault
glfwSwapBuffers();
```

Comment: Are you actually allocating memory for the mesh?

Comment: printf("%f", m.vertices[47]); shows that everything is ok with struct mesh.

Answer (score 4):

From the spec :

```
count : Specifies the number of indices to be rendered.
```

You have 3 coordinates per index, so

```
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, mesh->numVertices / 3)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solved problem. Segfault remains :]

Comment: Do you bind your vertex array ? glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayId);

Comment: @Calvin glBindVertexArrays is to use VAOs, which are NOT required or even used here.

Comment: You're drawing quads, so it should be / 4, not /3.

Comment: @Matias Valdenego - /4 also not work :] It's could be a bug in driver? I use Linux with NVidia.

Comment: @BPS I doubt it, this is a "common" issue because you're not passing the correct data or correct sizes.

Comment: @Matias, @BPS : My mistake, I meant glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); But as a side note, the default VAO has been deprecated, so it is required (even if nobody does it)

Comment: @Matias : Are you sure about the /4 ? this would mean that there is 48/4 indices...